# Visual Studio 2012 Database project in TFS will not store schema compare password?

Tags: visual-studio-2012, tfs, database-project

I have VS2012 and TFS2012. I have a database project with a schema compare file (.scmp) defining my source and target to compare. The target is a connection to a SQL 2012 database. with SQL authentication. I have defined the connection on my machine and checked "Save my password".

I have added the .scmp file to my solution and checked it into TFS. When a colleague gets the project and tries using the .scmp to do a schema compare, an error occurs.

> Error 1   Validation error in the source: Unable to restore the
>   password.  Enter a password by editing the connection.    0   0

He then needs to edit the connection (where the password field is blank) and enter the proper password. After doing so, the schema compare will work.

How can I get the password to be part of the TFS checkin so we don't have to update it every time someone gets the latest version?

I see there are some advanced settings including a security section in the Edit Connection dialogue. Any suggestions are much appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: It seems to be a known bug that MS was supposed to fix in VS2010 SP1 but now claims they won't fix. https://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/551711